# Farseer: Difficulties with ContactListener

Tags: xna, c#, physics, farseer-physics-engine

How can I register the ContactListener in XNA? In the box2d manual is written:

9.4 Contact Listener
...
At run-time you can create an instance of the listener and register it with b2World::SetContactListener. Be sure your listener remains in scope while the world object exists.

http://www.box2d.org/manual.html#_Toc258082975

How can I do that? I want to use PreSolve to disable collision between the character and some tiles.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved with:

```
world.ContactManager.PreSolve += new PreSolveDelegate(PreSolve);
```